# Android Beacon Library restart monitoring, dynamic regions

Tags: android, android-asynctask, beacon

First of all, excuse my English if you find some mistakes and thank you for your help. I have a program consuming an API REST Service to retrieve a list of Regions to monitor every X seconds. I am using Android Beacon Library to monitor the regions and I want to be able to stop monitoring those regions, get a new list, and then start monitoring the new regions. I have this code (simplified) so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer {
  // Code
  Timer task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      handler.post(new rRunnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          new MyAsyncTask().execute(some_params);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Buncle savedInstanceState) {
    // Code
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    // Set parsers (iBeacon, Eddystone-UID, Eddystone-URL)
    beaconManager.bind(this);
    Log.i(TAG, "Using Android Beacon Library version: "+ org.altbeacon.beacon.BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
      // Get info of regions and show a list of regions detected on UI
      Log.i(TAG, "Inside of: " + region.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
      // Get info of regions and show a list of regions detected on UI
      Log.i(TAG, "Outside of: " + region.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
      Log.i(TAG, "State: " + state);
    }

    // execute async task to stop monitoring, get new regions list and then
    // start monitoring again
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 30000); 
  }

  private class MyAsyncTask extends AyncTask<String, Void, List<Region>> {
    @Override
    protected List<Region> doInBackground(String... params) {
      // Get list of regions from server
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Region> result) {
      // For loop to stop monitoring all regions
      for (Region region : beaconManager.getMonitoredRegions()) {
        try {
          beaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
          Log.i(TAG, "Stop monitoring: " + region.toString());
        } catch (RemoteException e) { }
      }
      Log.i(TAG, "Nº of regions: " + beaconManager.getMonitoredRegions().size());
      // For loop to start monitoring new regions
      for (Region region : result) {
        try {
          beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
          Log.i(TAG, "Start monitoring: " + region.toString());
        } catch (RemoteException e) { }
      }
      Log.i(TAG, "Nº of regions: " + beaconManager.getMonitoredRegions().size());
    }
  }
```

There is no syntax mistake in the code and the app do not crash. When I execute the app, it calls the server, gets the list of regions to monitor and then starts monitoring the regions. Then a list of the regions monitored appears on the screen when beacons are in range. For now everything seems ok. Then, the app stops monitoring the regions, requests the new list of regions and starts monitoring the new ones. I tried with 3 regions the first time, and 2 the second time and the app logged that it started monitoring 3 regions, then stoped monitoring those 3 and then it started monitoring the 2 new ones. Everything seems fine but while it says that it started monitoring the new regions, the app never shows the regions monitored on screen again when beacons are in range.

I want to know if the problem is the way I have established the process to get the regions and to monitor them.

Is seems that after restarting the monitoring with the new regions, it does not fire the didEnterRegion and didExitRegion.

EDIT: I am testing the example with 3 beacons and 3 regions. The first beacon uses iBeacon, the second one uses Eddystone-UID and the third one uses Eddystone-URL. Each region is configured to detect one specific beacon.

Logcat (Simplified, the ids of the beacons and regions are all correct):

```
Using Android Beacon Library version: 2.7
Nº of regions: 0
Start monitoring: id1: ibeacon_id id2: ibeacon_major id3: ibeacon_minor
Start monitoring: id1: eddystone_namespace id2: eddystone_id id3: null
Start monitoring: id1: eddystone_url id2: null id3: null
Nº of regions: 3
State: 1
Inside of: id1: eddystone_url id2: null id3: null
State: 1
Inside of: id1: eddystone_namespace id2: eddystone_id id3: null
State: 1
Inside of: id1: ibeacon_id id2: ibeacon_major id3: ibeacon_minor

30 seconds later (more or less)...
I have not changed the regions provided by the server.

Stop monitoring: id1: ibeacon_id id2: ibeacon_major id3: ibeacon_minor
Stop monitoring: id1: eddystone_namespace id2: eddystone_id id3: null
Stop monitoring: id1: eddystone_url id2: null id3: null
Nº of regions: 0
Start monitoring: id1: ibeacon_id id2: ibeacon_major id3: ibeacon_minor
Start monitoring: id1: eddystone_namespace id2: eddystone_id id3: null
Start monitoring: id1: eddystone_url id2: null id3: null
Nº of regions: 3

30 seconds later (more or less)...

Stop monitoring: id1: ibeacon_id id2: ibeacon_major id3: ibeacon_minor
Stop monitoring: id1: eddystone_namespace id2: eddystone_id id3: null
Stop monitoring: id1: eddystone_url id2: null id3: null
Nº of regions: 0
Start monitoring: id1: ibeacon_id id2: ibeacon_major id3: ibeacon_minor
Start monitoring: id1: eddystone_namespace id2: eddystone_id id3: null
Start monitoring: id1: eddystone_url id2: null id3: null
Nº of regions: 3

Keep repeating...
```

As we can see, the events didEnterRegion, didExitRegion and didDetermineStateForRegion are not fired anymore.

Comment: Can you confirm which library version you are using? `Log.d(TAG, "Using Android Beacon Library version: "+org.altbeacon.beacon.BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);` In the method that restarts monitoring regions, can you add log statements that show the regions for the stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion and for the startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion calls, and then attach the log statement output to your question?  It would also be helpful to know the identifiers of the beacons you are transmitting that are not providing region entry events.

Comment: I have added the log information and made the code clearer.

Comment: By the way, I have tested the app while using other apps to detect beacons (but not at the same time as the test above) like Locate, Beacon Manager or Estimote and when I execute some of them at the same time, in the end none of the detect the beacons until I left just one of them scanning. Is that a normal behavior?

Comment: Is this in the background or foreground?  If you wait 10 minutes, do you still get no entry/exit events?  It may be helpful to turn on full debug logging  and capture it in LogCat  for about 5 minutes.  This will be big, so you could link to this as a Pastebin or Gist.  You can turn on debug logging with beaconManager.setDebug(true)

Comment: This is in the foreground. Here is the log https://gist.github.com/Elolawyn/ffc71c9f5fec7b0f34c40c078dd8fa3b

Answer (score 0):

There was an undiscovered (until now) bug in the 2.7 release in the [Android Beacon Library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library) that stopped scanning on Android 5+ devices after stopping scanning on all regions.  Scanning would not start again without unbinding from the service and rebinding to it.

With debug logging turned on, this showed up as:

```
04-11 08:35:07.655  D/BeaconService: stopMonitoring called
04-11 08:35:07.655  D/BeaconService: Currently monitoring 0 regions.
04-11 08:35:07.655  D/CycledLeScanner: stop called
04-11 08:35:07.655  D/CycledLeScanner: disabling scan
...
04-11 08:35:07.663  D/BeaconService: Currently monitoring 1 regions.
04-11 08:35:07.663  D/CycledLeScanner: start called
04-11 08:35:07.663  D/CycledLeScanner: scanning already started
```

Changes to the way this works were made in the 2.8 release, and I have verified that the bug no longer exists in 2.8.   With the 2.8 version, the second half looks like this:

```
04-12 18:15:07.623  D/BeaconService: Currently monitoring 1 regions.
04-12 18:13:06.938  D/CycledLeScanner: start called
04-12 18:13:06.938  D/CycledLeScanner: starting a new scan cycle
04-12 18:13:06.939  D/CycledLeScanner: starting a new bluetooth le scan
```

With 2.8, you can stop monitoring all regions, start monitoring a new region, and you will immediately get an entry callback if the beacon is in the vicinity.  The easy solution is to upgrade to 2.8, either through JCenter or by downloading directly [here.](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/releases/tag/2.8)

Comment: I have updated the library without changing the code and now it seems like it's working properly. The log says: "I/BeaconService: stop monitoring recieved" and "I/BeaconService: start monitoring recieved" afterwards. There is just a little problem: now it doesn't detect beacons at all xD. Beacons ID are all ok and other apps can find the beacons.

Comment: One of the changes in 2.8 is that the library remembers the state of monitored regions across app restarts.  So if you stop the app and restart with the beacon still transmitting, you won't get an extra `didEnterRegion` callback.  This may be what you are seeing.  Try actually turning off the beacon, waiting for an exit, and turning it back on again to get an entry event.

Comment: I am using Estimote sleep mode and the app does not detect if I am leaving/entering the regions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Are you saying you cannot get region exit events  when the beacon stops transmitting or the mobile device leaves the vicinity?